# jquery function not firing when I use datatable.fnAddData to append the HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

jquery function not firing when I use `dataTable.fnAddData` to append the HTML string.

So I have a function `populateDataTable()`, there are two columns I needed to render an icon instead of data from JSON. 
Hence, I tried to like appending the HTML string including classes for the element in `fnAddData()`. But somehow it's not firing the click event on the icon.

```
  function populateDataTable(data) {
    $("#customerTable").DataTable().clear();
    var length = Object.keys(data).length;
    for(var i = 1; i < length+1; i++) {      

    var index = i - 1;
    var name = data[index].name;
    var queue = data[index].queue;
    var expire = data[index].expire;

    $('#customerTable').dataTable().fnAddData( [
        i,
        name,
        queue,
        '<td id="tb-manage-key" class="tb-manage-key"><div class="tb-btn manage-key-btn switch-view" data-hide="manageCustomers" data-title="@Resources.ManageKeys" data-target="manageKeys"><span></span></div></td>',
        '<td class="tb-manage-subs"><div class="tb-btn manage-subs-btn switch-view" data-hide="manageCustomers" data-title="@Resources.ManageSubscriptions" data-target="manageSubscriptions"><span></span></div></td>',
        expire,
        name
    ]);
}}



$('.tb-btn.switch-view').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  switchView(this);
 console.log('Testing'); //not firing
});
```

Icon is showing, but not firing click event as it supposed to be. Attached below shows that we can see it appends the div as expected. 
[image]

---

**Solutions**

Adding the click event within the `populateDataTable()` works.

```
$('#customerTable tbody').on('click', '.tb-btn.switch-view', function() {
    switchView(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a different syntax to listen to the click event...

```
$('td').on('click', '.tb-btn.switch-view', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  switchView(this);
 console.log('Testing'); //not firing
});
```

Comment: thanks! silly me. working now after changing syntax and placed in within the populateDataTable() function.